# VIM replace part of filename with something else similar to ZSH cd

Tags: zsh, vim

I have recently switched to using VIM. I work on multiple branches of the same code so often two files will have very similar paths (example: /home/user/turkey/code/helloworld.cpp) and I would like to diff the same file in another branch (example: /home/user/kangaroo/code/helloworld.cpp).

ZSH has cd command where one can just say `cd turkey kangaroo` to change the path. I would like to find/create something similar in my vimrc (example: `diffsplit vert turkey kangaroo`). Any suggestions on how to go about this?

I know that the full path to the current file is stored in `expand('%:p')` but am not sure how I would go about changing the contents of this. It seems like the vim replace is limited to editing files rather than registers. I would like to do this in memory instead of having it edit a file.

Comment: could the  `turkey`  show multiple times in the path? like `/home/usr/turkey/turkey(this needs to be replaced)/turkeyCode/foo.file` and branch is `/home/usr/turkey/kanaroo/turkeyCode/foo.file` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this codes in your vimrc:

```
let s:branches=['/foo/','/bar/']
function! ShowDiff()
    let other = expand('%:p')
    let do_diff = 0
    if match(other, s:branches[0])>0
        let other = substitute(other, s:branches[0], s:branches[1],'')
        let do_diff = 1
    elseif match(other, s:branches[1])>0
        let other = substitute(other, s:branches[1], s:branches[0],'')
        let do_diff = 1
    endif
    if do_diff
        exec 'vert diffsplit '. other
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <F5> :call ShowDiff()<cr>
```

then press `<f5>` in normal mode will open the same file in corresponding branch (dir) in vert split and in diff mode.

e.g. now you are editing

```
/home/whatever/foo/code/foo.txt
```

Pressing `<F5>` will vert-split and diff:

```
/home/whatever/bar/code/foo.txt
```

it searches the complete directory name, like `/foo/` or `/bar/` you can change the `s:branches` to match your needs. like `let s:branches=['/turkey/','/kangaroo/']`

A small demo:[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Kent! That was exactly what I needed! I changed a couple of things to come up with the directory automatically but heavily relied on yours. Here's my end result:

 function! ShowDiff()
 let filePath = expand('%:p')
 call inputsave()
 let newStream = input("New stream name: ")
 call inputrestore()
 
 let filePath = substitute(filePath, $USER."_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*", $USER."_".newStream, '')
 if filereadable(filePath)
     exec 'vert diffsplit ' . filePath
 else
     echo "File doesn't exist in same location for other branch"
 endif
    endfunction
    nnoremap <F5> :call ShowDiff()<cr>